# (ERROR) mqttc.loop_forever() & SensorID = json_Dict['Sensor_ID']

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm trying to store my MQTT data in SQLITE database on raspberry (communicating with wemos d1). What am I doing wrong to get the error below? I appreciate your help very much. Thank you in advance.

**CODE mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py :**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from store_Sensor_Data_to_DB import sensor_Data_Handler

# MQTT Settings 
MQTT_Broker = "localhost"
MQTT_Port = 1883
Keep_Alive_Interval = 45
MQTT_Topic = "kuca/primanje/kanta01/razina"

#Subscribe to all Sensors at Base Topic
def on_connect(self, userdata, flags, rc):
       mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_Topic, 0)

#Save Data into DB Table
def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
    # This is the Master Call for saving MQTT Data into DB
    # For details of "sensor_Data_Handler" function please refer "sensor_data_to_db.py"
    print "MQTT Data Received..."
    print "MQTT Topic: " + msg.topic  
    print "Data: " + msg.payload
    sensor_Data_Handler(msg.topic, msg.payload)

def on_subscribe(self, obj, mid, granted_qos):    
    pass

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

# Connect
mqttc.connect(MQTT_Broker, int(MQTT_Port), int(Keep_Alive_Interval))

# Continue the network loop
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

**CODE : store_Sensor_Data_to_DB.py**

```
import json
import sqlite3

# SQLite DB Name
DB_Name =  "IoT.db"

#===============================================================
# Database Manager Class

class DatabaseManager():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_Name)
        self.conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys = on')
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def add_del_update_db_record(self, sql_query, args=()):
        self.cur.execute(sql_query, args)
        self.conn.commit()
        return

    def __del__(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()

#===============================================================
# Functions to push Sensor Data into Database

# Function to save Temperature to DB Table
def DHT22_Temp_Data_Handler(jsonData):
    #Parse Data 
    json_Dict = json.loads(jsonData)
    SensorID = json_Dict['Sensor_ID']
    Data_and_Time = json_Dict['Date']
    Temperature = json_Dict['Temperature']

    #Push into DB Table
    dbObj = DatabaseManager()
    dbObj.add_del_update_db_record("insert into DHT22_Temperature_Data (SensorID, Date_n_Time, Temperature) values (?,?,?)",[SensorID, Data_and_Time, Temperature])
    del dbObj
    print "Inserted Temperature Data into Database."
    print ""

# Function to save Humidity to DB Table
def DHT22_Humidity_Data_Handler(jsonData):
    #Parse Data 
    json_Dict = json.loads(jsonData)
    SensorID = json_Dict['Sensor_ID']
    Data_and_Time = json_Dict['Date']
    Humidity = json_Dict['Humidity']

    #Push into DB Table
    dbObj = DatabaseManager()
    dbObj.add_del_update_db_record("insert into DHT22_Humidity_Data (SensorID, Date_n_Time, Humidity) values (?,?,?)",[SensorID, Data_and_Time, Humidity])
    del dbObj
    print "Inserted Humidity Data into Database."
    print ""


#===============================================================
# Master Function to Select DB Funtion based on MQTT Topic

def sensor_Data_Handler(Topic, jsonData):
    if Topic == "kuca/primanje/kanta01/razina":
        DHT22_Temp_Data_Handler(jsonData)
    elif Topic == "kuca/primanje/kanta01/razina":
        DHT22_Humidity_Data_Handler(jsonData)
```

ERROR

```
pi@Pi:~/Desktop/SQLITE $ python mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py
MQTT Data Received...
MQTT Topic: kuca/primanje/kanta01/razina
Data: 68.00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py", line 43, in <module>
    mqttc.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1481, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1003, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1284, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1849, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2305, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2500, in _handle_publish
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2647, in _handle_on_message
    self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py", line 29, in on_message
    sensor_Data_Handler(msg.topic, msg.payload)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/SQLITE/store_Sensor_Data_to_DB.py", line 74, in sensor_Data_Handler
    DHT22_Temp_Data_Handler(jsonData)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/SQLITE/store_Sensor_Data_to_DB.py", line 42, in DHT22_Temp_Data_Handler
    SensorID = json_Dict['Sensor_ID']
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the value passed into the `DHT22_Temp_Data_Handler(jsonData)` function is a float not a JSON string.

This can be seen from the output before the error:

```
pi@Pi:~/Desktop/SQLITE $ python mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py
MQTT Data Received...
MQTT Topic: kuca/primanje/kanta01/razina
Data: 68.00
```

As you can see the payload from the topic is `68.00` not a JSON string, so when you parse it you end up with just the same float not the dict with the values you are trying to read.

Comment: But thats what I want, 68.00 thats the value from my wemos and ultrasonic sensor.

Comment: yes, but you are trying to turn 68.00 into a json object and then extract a field called `Sensor_ID` from it. This is of course not possible

Comment: ohh, yes. I understand you. Could you be so kind and tell me which part of code do I have to change. I really appreciate your help and I want to apologize for bothering you, I'm new in this language.

Comment: Not really, the code is expecting the sensor to send a JSON message so it totally setup to expect that. The fix is to change the message the sensor sends so it is JSON with the data you want.